# Kuratowski's theorem in every case?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have the following graph $G$ (from Chartrand and Zhang, page 235, figure 9.9) [image: figure 9.9, a nonplanar graph]

which is based on a maximal planar graph on 7 vertices with an additional edge (labeled $uv$).  This graph is nonplanar because $m>3n-6$. Also, this graph does not contain either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as a subgraph (this is proved in the text).  My question is why doesn't this contradict Kuratowski's theorem?  Shouldn't there be a subdivision of one of these contained in $G$?  But there are no vertices of degree two in this graph, so I'm not sure what subgraph I can take to build either of the critical graphs.  I know the subgraph needs the edge $uv$, but that's all I know.

At this point in the text, contractions haven't been discussed, and subdivisions were just introduced, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a subdivided $K_{3,3}$ embedded in this graph. Each of $u,z,s$ are connected to each of $v,t,y$ by distinct edges of your graph, except that $u$ and $y$ are connected the two edge path $uxy$.

Comment: It took me about 45 minutes to follow the examples in the text, and now I think I understand the subgraph/subdivision distinction.  I found this $K_{3,3}$ and then came back to find your answer - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

$\{u,s,x,v,t\}$ forms a subdivision of $K_5$ in the graph. This can be formed by deleting the edges from $y$ and $z$ to $s$ and $t$, then smoothing out the path $xyzv$.

Comment: Thank you - this was helpful - I found a $K_{3,3}$, but I wasn't sure about the $K_5$.

Answer (score 1):

Check again the statement of Kuratowski's theorem. It does not talk about subgraphs, but some kind of graph minors. This example is a perfect illustration why Kuratowski's theorem SHOULD NOT talk about subgraphs.

Comment: Thank you - it calls for a "subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$"  I wasn't sure how to find that.